# Maven project.build.directory

Tags: maven

In Maven, what does the `project.build.directory` refer to? I am a bit confused, does it reference the source code directory or the target directory in the Maven project?

Comment: The ambiguity should have never have found its way into the mainstream!

Answer (score 277, accepted):

You can find those maven properties in the super pom.

You find the jar here:

```
${M2_HOME}/lib/maven-model-builder-3.0.3.jar
```

Open the jar with 7-zip or some other archiver (or use the jar tool).

Navigate to

```
org/apache/maven/model
```

There you'll find the `pom-4.0.0.xml`.

It contains all those "short cuts":

```xml
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <testOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <scriptSourceDirectory>src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        ...
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

---

### Update

After some lobbying I am adding a [link to the `pom-4.0.0.xml`](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/trunk/maven-model-builder/src/main/resources/org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml#L53). This allows you to see the properties without opening up the local jar file.

Comment: I would suggest an online reference instead of file which is archived into jar. This: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-model/maven.html

Comment: @khmarbaise Well that's nice as well but it doesn't show you the default value of `project.build.directory` for example. That's what I wanted to show.

Comment: The github mirror allows linking to a specific line number: https://github.com/apache/maven-3/blob/trunk/maven-model-builder/src/main/resources/org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml#L53 
Otherwise, it's in svn at: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/maven-3/trunk/maven-model-builder/src/main/resources/org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml

Comment: @MartinEllis OK, I have updated my answer with a link as well. Thank you!

Comment: I searched the source of the maven repo at https://github.com/apache/maven.  A relatively small number of hits (9).  Nothing sets that property directly.  It's got to be set somewhere!
This URL shows the search results I saw: https://github.com/apache/maven/search?p=1&q=%22project.build.directory%22&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: False. This is only a subset of project properties from the `POM`. It doesn't include core properties like `project.basedir`, and others.

Comment: Link to doc: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#the-super-pom which matches https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/maven-model-builder/src/main/resources/org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml

Answer (score 61):

It points to your top level output directory (which by default is `target`):

https://web.archive.org/web/20150527103929/http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide

**EDIT:** As has been pointed out, Codehaus is now sadly defunct. You can find details about these properties from Sonatype here:

http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html#resource-filtering-sect-project-properties

> If you are ever trying to reference output directories in Maven, you should never use a literal value like *target/classes*. Instead you should use property references to refer to these directories.
>
> ```
>     project.build.sourceDirectory
>     project.build.scriptSourceDirectory
>     project.build.testSourceDirectory
>     project.build.outputDirectory
>     project.build.testOutputDirectory
>     project.build.directory
> ```
>
> `sourceDirectory`, `scriptSourceDirectory`, and `testSourceDirectory` provide access to the source directories for the project. `outputDirectory` and `testOutputDirectory` provide access to the directories where Maven is going to put bytecode or other build output. `directory` refers to the directory which contains all of these output directories.

Comment: The codehause.org hosting has been terminated and this link does not work any more.

Comment: Yes, true and sad. I've updated with a working link and quoted the relevant section of the linked page.

Comment: ...so `project.base.dir` points to the root directory of the project where the pom.xml is. That's why after that, `project.build.directory` defined by Maven is `${project.basedir}/target`. Thanks guys, I didn't know this.

Comment: Although seems to be true, but how did you get this info: "project.base.dir points to the root directory of the project where the pom.xml is". Where I can see this definition?

Comment: suppose your project is called project-A, and under project-A, a pom.xml is declared, then
`${project.build.sourceDirectory}` points to `project-A/src/main/java`,
`${project.build.scriptSourceDirectory}` points to `project-A/src/main/scripts`,
`${project.build.testSourceDirectory}` points to `project-A/src/test/java`,
`${project.build.directory}` points to `project-A/target`,
`${project.build.directory}` points to `project-A/target/classes`,
`${project.build.testOutputDirectory}` points to `project-A/target/test-classes`.

Comment: This is the only complete and accurate answer.

Comment: The comment by sc30, is the most 'to the point' answer.

Comment: @sc30 Please update the 5th property to,  
`${project.build.outputDirectory}` points to `project-A/target/classes`

Answer (score 7):

You can find the most up to date answer for the value in your project just execute the

```
mvn3 help:effective-pom
```

command and find the `<build> ... <directory>` tag's value in the result aka in the effective-pom. It will show the value of the Super POM unless you have overwritten.

Comment: This doesn't show some of the core properties, like `project.basedir`. In other areas it's incomplete, also.

Comment: @ingyhere That is correct, the effective pom does not contain the `project.basedir`. Actually, the reason is that even the super POM doesn't contain. What else do you miss from the effective pom? It sounds interesting to me if you could give some details.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from @Verhás István answer (which I like), I was expecting a one-liner for the question:

`${project.reporting.outputDirectory}` resolves to `target/site` in your project.