# Replacing tokens in web.xml using Google Maven replacer for WAR packaging

Tags: maven, maven-replacer-plugin

My `web.xml` is under `${project.root}\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF`.

I would like to use the `com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin` to replace some tokens inside it **when it is packaged in the WAR but not in the source directory**.

I tried:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>replace</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <file>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</file>
    <replacements>
      <replacement>
        <token>@@sec.level@@</token>
        <value>local</value>
      </replacement>
    </replacements>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But I got

```
[ERROR] File '.\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml' does not exist
```

Since this file is not copied under the `target` file structure and is just taken from the source directly into the WAR (or so I think), how do I reference its path in the above `configuration->file` parameter so that the replacer finds it and replaces the tokens?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the path as follows

```
${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

More information on different variable [maven properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354531/maven-project-build-directory)

Comment: however, that changes the file in the source and i want to leave the source untouched (keep the token) and only change it in the build and the WAR file

Comment: have you tried using ${project.build.directory}, but you need to provide proper phase ( as it has to be done before creating the war file)