# Referring to a generated jar inside a Maven pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

In my `pom.xml` file I have the `maven-shade-plugin` for generating an uber jar. This uber jar has the version of my app in it, such as `app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`. Then, I use the `launch4j-maven-plugin` to wrap that into an `exe` file, but to achieve that I have a configuration that looks like this:

```
<configuration>
    <jar>target/app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</jar>
```

Is there a way to use a variable or placeholder here and not to have to hard-code the filename of the jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be:

```
${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar
```

Please see:

> [Maven project.build.directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354531/maven-project-build-directory)